# Writting to a cell range with openpyxl in a class

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I am trying to write to a cell range using openpyxl as a funtion in a class (not sure if I am doing it write)

I want to write to the cells in days_of_the_month_cells the caluclated values of total_cull, total_all, total_all, total_good, total_hold, and total_joblot

in this example it will be the same values for every cell range

**excel_writer.py**

```
from datetime import date
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

days_of_the_month_cells = {
    "Week 1": {
        "Sun": "D6:D22",
        "Mon": "E6:E22",
        "Tue": "F6:F22",
        "Wed": "G6:G22",
        "Wed": "H6:H22",
        "Thu": "I6:I22",
        "Fri": "J6:J22",
        "Sat": "K6:K22",
    }, "Week 2": {
        "Sun": "D23:D39",
        "Mon": "E23:E39",
        "Tue": "F23:F39",
        "Wed": "G23:G39",
        "Wed": "H23:H39",
        "Thu": "I23:I39",
        "Fri": "J23:J39",
        "Sat": "K23:K39",
    }, "Week 3": {
        "Sun": "D40:D56",
        "Mon": "E40:E56",
        "Tue": "F40:F56",
        "Wed": "G40:G56",
        "Wed": "H40:H56",
        "Thu": "I40:I56",
        "Fri": "J40:J56",
        "Sat": "K40:K56",
    }, "Week 4": {
        "Sun": "D57:D73",
        "Mon": "E57:E73",
        "Tue": "F57:F73",
        "Wed": "G57:G73",
        "Wed": "H57:H73",
        "Thu": "I57:I73",
        "Fri": "J57:J73",
        "Sat": "K57:K73",
    }

}


class Write_To_Excel:
    def __init__(self, cull, all, broke, good, hold, joblot):
        self.cull = cull
        self.all = all
        self.broke = broke
        self.good = good
        self.hold = hold
        self.joblot = joblot

    def write(calculated_cull):
        wb = load_workbook('XLSXs/input/Finished Goods Daily Report 2022.xlsx')

        ws = wb.active
       
        # ???

        wb.save('XLSXs/output/Finished Goods Daily Report 2022.xlsx')
```

**main.py**

```
from excel_writer import Write_To_Excel

total_cull = ending_inventory.sum()
total_all = Total_Riper("all.pdf").calculate()
total_broke = Total_Riper("broke.pdf").calculate()
total_good = Total_Riper("good.pdf").calculate()
total_hold = Total_Riper("hold.pdf").calculate()
total_joblot = Total_Riper("joblot.pdf").calculate()

Write_To_Excel(total_cull, total_all, total_good, total_good, total_hold, total_joblot).write()
```

Any help you can provide would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read cell ranges and write to them this way

```py
from datetime import date
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

# for every week
for vs in days_of_the_month_cells.values():
    # for every day, range
    for k, rng in vs.items():
        # for row in range
        for cs in ws[rng]:
            # for col in row
            for c in cs:
                # assign the value k for all that range
                c.value = k

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```